# Styling asp:DropDownList with CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have created a small CSS, which I wanted to use to make my own styled DropDownList. I don't know if there is some sort of incompatibility and I'm still learning CSS and ASP.net, but when I tried my code in an online CSS tester, it worked perfectly.

```
.select {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #212121, 0 -1px #191919 inset;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  select {
    padding-right: 18px;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

label:after {
  content: '<>';
  font: 11px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 8px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

label:before {
  content: '';
  right: 6px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
}
```

This is my DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="select" id="DropPoke1" Width="80" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropPoke1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Have I done something wrong or is it just not possible?

**Edit:** After adding the following line to my aspx, it worked:

```
<link href="CustomDropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: This is working fine on my side, have your properly included style sheet?

Comment: @SirajHussain Thank you. I've not done that and now it works perfectly fine. First time CSS and you just saved me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine. Please make sure you have properly included style sheet.

Comment: Adding <link href="CustomDropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> did the trick. What a silly mistake.

Comment: It happens some times :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are not calling your element by own created classes, you may need to inspect with chrome (or similar) your html.

calling the css by generic tags as "label" often won't work as a `asp:Label`  use to be translated into an `html span`, not a `html label`

Comment: I see. I've changed the tags to tags which are definitely unique, but it still does not work. does ASP.net even support style changes on their DropDownLists?

Comment: yes, it does if You call the elements properly. be sure your css sheet is working propely adding on top something like `body{background-color:red;}` to check if the css sheet is working.

Comment: I've done that, but I see absolutely nothing. I've defined the CSS as a class and referred to that class in the "CssClass" property of the DropDownList, but it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: @Kohnarik Have you checked your HTML code with Firebug (Firefox) or Webtools (Chrome)?

Comment: In the code shown in the OP you have your `select` class, but you're still calling the element directly. Is this possibly the problem?

Comment: @DrewKennedy What do you mean?

Comment: You're calling `select` and not `.select`. It should work either way, but it's worth a try if this is present in your css file.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Ah I see. I've already tried that, but it still doesn't work.